# Displaying interstital ads before load fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob

When i open fragment interstitial ad shows after some 4-5 seconds. How can i fix that interstitial ad shows before loaded fragment view

```
        mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you load ad when you close:**

```
          override fun onAdClosed() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        }
```

**Here, when its loaded, you show again:**

```
               if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
                mInterstitialAd.show()
            }
```

this is endless.

if you don't want it to show again and again, cancel one of the two.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it, but how can i show intertitial ad before load fragment?

Comment: If i understand you in the right way, on the Activity which you make the transaction of the fragment, before you make commit(), show the ad, when ad is closed (onAdClosed) make the transaction / commit.

Comment: Or you can show in the fragment onViewCreated method.

Comment: {
                    fragment = UserFragment().newInstance()
                    interstitalAd()
                    loadFragment(fragment)
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }